# Unity3d Text Assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please Help me
How to edit this file 
This Is a unity Text assets

When i edit this file ,the game error'/not work

This Is the file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/l91jjyw42b17xvi/AllLanguageIndonesian-CAB-AllLanguageIndonesian-13371969181549940066.txt/file

Please help me

Sorry for bad English
I am from Indonesia

Comment: Please describe your problem, what do you want to change in this file?

Comment: I want to change some of the words in the text but the game is broken

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to read this book in, and display it? You should read in a few lines at a time, or read it in, and store pages in an array of strings, or something similar.  If so try something like this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Here's some code (from https://forum.unity.com/threads/reading-massive-text-files.358014/)

```
using(var file = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Your_big_file.txt"))
{
  file.ReadLine();
}
```